# Inno Setup Return Values From A Page as a Parameter

Tags: batch-file, installation, inno-setup

So im trying to make an installer in Inno setup. how do I use user input (so a directory) as a parameter for running a batch file? (The user input having been collected on a page). Thanks

Comment: It is possible. Show us a simplified code you have. Or at least tell if you're using `CreateInput...` functions to create your custom pages or if your pages are custom (created by `CreateCustomPage` function), tell us which components are you having there. But better would be to show your real (ideally simplified) code.

Comment: My code is a complete mess though but I could try and tidy it up a bit, however like I said it is so awful I will probably start again as it is a fairly small amount of code, so could I have some example code of how to do something like this? (sorry I am completely new to inno setup)

Comment: Ok, so let's start looking at the [`CodeDlg.iss`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Examples/CodeDlg.iss) example showing how to create custom input pages. This example is shipped with InnoSetup in its `..\Examples` folder. Try to create it by yourself and if you'll have trouble with something specific, come back and ask a new question. Show me some code is not a proper question for StackOverflow. This site is mostly intended for specific questions. Your question is too broad to answer. Thanks! And welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Yes, I have already been through the CodeDlg.iss and thats where I got my pages from and I did try creating this by myself and it didnt work. But okay for a more specific question how do I use user input (so a directory) as a parameter for running a batch file?

Comment: If that's your question, please [`edit your post`](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18533931/edit) and change it accordingly.

Comment: Happy now? Ive changed my post to be EXACTLY what I just wrote..... I thought it was the same but I have changed it.... Now can you answer the question?

Comment: This site is about questions and answers. Not about *please give me some code and I'll specify you what I really want in comment*. And, don't be offensive. You need a help, not me. Take into account, that those rules are not mine. Yet another thing to specify. What is *a batch file* ? Is that a batch file shipped with your setup or a batch file expected to be on the target user's machine ? It's important because if the first option, the commands from that batch file might be reritten to the setup's `[Run]` section. Please update your question once again and include this information there.

Comment: Okay I dont mind giving you more information but please ask for it in one question rather than making me change my question and if you are asking questions based on other questions then couldnt we do this in chat rather than in the comments? and just to let you know its in the run section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a directory input page you can use the `TInputDirWizardPage` built-in wizard page type. In the following script you can see how to create an input directory page with one field whose value is then passed as a parameter to the batch file executed from the `[Run]` section of the script:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\YourBatch.bat"; Parameters: "{code:GetBatchParams}"

[Code]
var
  DirInputPage: TInputDirWizardPage;

function GetBatchParams(Value: string): string;
begin
  Result := DirInputPage.Values[0];
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  DirInputPage := CreateInputDirPage(wpWelcome, 'Caption', 'Description', 
    'SubCaption', False, '');

  DirInputPage.Add('Directory to be passed to batch file as parameter');
  DirInputPage.Values[0] := ExpandConstant('{userappdata}\Initial Directory');
end;
```